# Xpages - inPlaceForms bind to separate java beans

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino, ibm-domino

I love using managed java beans with xpages, but there is still one scenario, which i couldn't solve yet.
I have an application, that shows some entries of a database and allows editing them with an inplace form.

[image]

Each form is bind to the back-end document. I want to use a java bean also for that with the ability to bind fields to values in the bean.
I know, that i can do something with lists and hashmaps, but that is not the same. Or is it possible, to handle a list of objects from a class?
Has someone an idea, how to handle that?

Answer (score 4):

Start by creating a simple `Person.java` POJO. Something like this:

```
public Person {
    String firstName;
   
    public getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
    }

    public setFirstName(String to) {
      this.firstName = to;
    }

    //etcetera...
}
```

Make sure that every property you want to edit has a getter & setter.

You now have 2 options:

- The list of people is a `List<Person>` and when you edit one, you edit the object directly from that list.
- When the user wants to edit an entry, you pass (for instance) the note ID of the document from the list to the inplace form, get the document, construct a `Person` object and use that as the binding in the form.

Assuming that the instance of the `Person` is called `person`, you can bind them to the inputs like:

`<xp:inputText value="#{person.firstName} />`

For the save action in the inplace form, I would create a separate `PersonRepo` class with a static save function that consumes the current `Person` object and saves it to the database:

```
public class PersonRepo {

  public static void savePerson( Person person ) {
    Database db = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase();
    Document doc = db.createDocument();
    doc.replaceItemValue("firstName" , firstName);
    doc.save();        
  }

}
```

You can then call that from the save button:

`PersonRepo.savePerson(person);`

Comment: I'd add something like checking if the person object is already associated to a NotesDocument and get that instead of creating a new one by db.getDocumentByUNID(person.unid)...  But I assume this should be clear and your code is only an example...

Comment: Oh, looks easy. Can I use every java class, I've made?
Do I have to make an entry in the faces-config.xml as managed bean for that class?

Comment: Yes, you can call code from other classes you've made. You only need to add entries to the faces-config file if you're using managed beans, but in my example I've used none.